# Falha ao criar uma dll com construtores nas classes

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2017

Criei um cabeçalho com as definições da dll:

**globaldef.h**

```
#pragma once

#ifdef OPENXML_LIB
#define OPENXML __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define OPENXML __declspec(dllimport)
#endif // OPENXML_LIB
```

Criei duas classes até o momento:

**xmldoc.h**

```
#pragma once

#define XML_MODE_R 0
#define XML_MODE_RW 1

#include "globaldef.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

class OPENXML XmlDocumment {

public:

    XmlDocumment(std::string fileName, int mode);
    ~XmlDocumment();

    //Load xml content to string
    virtual std::string read();

private:

    //Xml file
    std::fstream xmlFile;
    std::string filename;
    int mode = 0;

};
```

**xmldoc.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h" 
#include "xmldoc.h" 
XmlDocumment::XmlDocumment(std::string fileName, int mode) { 
     this->filename = fileName; 
     this->mode = mode; 
} 
XmlDocumment::~XmlDocumment() { } 
std::string XmlDocumment::read() { 
     switch (mode) { 
         case XML_MODE_R: xmlFile.open(filename, std::ios::in); break; 
         case XML_MODE_RW: break; 
     } 
std::string content((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(xmlFile)), (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>())); 
xmlFile.close(); 
return content; 

}
```

E a outra classe no momento não comecei a escrever

**xmlnode.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "globaldef.h"

class OPENXML XmlNode {

public:


};
```

Tudo compila normalmente se não houver um construtor, porém se adiciono um construtor mesmo sem parâmetros algum ou vazio, o compilador emite o seguinte error:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Mostra o xmldoc.cpp

Comment: #include "stdafx.h"
#include "xmldoc.h"

XmlDocumment::XmlDocumment(std::string fileName, int mode)
{
 this->filename = fileName;
 this->mode = mode;
}

XmlDocumment::~XmlDocumment()
{

}

std::string XmlDocumment::read()
{
 
 switch (mode) {

 case XML_MODE_R:
  xmlFile.open(filename, std::ios::in);
  break;

 case XML_MODE_RW:
  break;
 }

 std::string content((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(xmlFile)), (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));
 xmlFile.close();

 return content;
}

Comment: Verifica se o nome das funções utilizadas no xmldoc estão correto, o visual studio de vez enquanto não avisa corretamente

Comment: Verifica se o DLL não está corrompido